# Why does Postman "form-data" body send differently than "raw>JSON" body?

Tags: api, postman, key-value, form-data

When I make a simple POST to my local intake endpoint, I can create a lead with the following very simple raw JSON body inside Postman:

```
{
    "identification_first_name": "New",
    "identification_last_name": "Lead",
    "identification_email_address": "new-intake2@email.com"
}
```

Now, I need to move my testing to use the "form-data" fields inside Postman as I need to test receiving a file, but when I copy over the exact fields into this form-data table, and add a file row, the endpoint does not receive anything. Why would it not just send these values in the exact same way that the RAW body does?

I would think just copying over the exact fields and values I am using in the RAW would work the exact same way? **Even if I just remove the new file field and send the exact same fields with the exact same values it still doesn't receive the body.** The API calls fine but the keys and values don't get passed into the request, it's just blank.

Do I need to prefix or change the references in the form-data section compared to raw>body? Or is Postman adding some different layering to this body so my API needs to adjust where it's looking, sending inside an extra array or object?

Thanks!